Two custom home pages for two focus modes whilst having a blank Home Screen when not in a focus mode
For the custom “Piloting” focus mode I have created, the Home Screen looks like this:

When I turn this focus mode off, the Home Screen is empty. This is how I would like it. It is one empty page with no any apps or widgets, if I scroll left, it goes straight to the App Library:

I am struggling to add a second Home Screen Page for a second focus mode, whilst retaining a blank Home Page when coming off the focus mode.
For example this “test” focus mode with the triangle symbol.
When I go to the Home Screen settings in this “test” focus mode only one option comes up, the one already being used in the “Piloting” focus mode.

How do I create a second page listed here in “my pages” to be used for a second focus mode. So that there are two home screens, one for each focus mode and the Home Screen being empty (no apps/widgets) when turning focus modes off?
